# Update plugin settings option_name for big plugin update

Tags: plugin-development, database, settings-api

I am working on a plugin update and have changed the settings option_name and key.

I would like that the old options are transferred to the new option_name.

The old option name is: plugin_options

The new being: plugin_settings_general

The keys have changed too, from "ga_accountId" to "ga_account_id".

I looked at [$wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) but could not working any thing out that worked.

This should work if I did not need to change the keys too.

```
// Get entire array
$plugin_options = get_option( 'plugin_options' );
// Update entire array
update_option( 'plugin_name_settings_general', $plugin_options );
// Delete old array
delete_option( 'plugin_options' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing array keys is more of a PHP problem

```
// Get entire array
$plugin_options = get_option( 'plugin_options' );

$new_options = array();

if( isset( $plugin_options['ga_accountId'] ) )
    $new_options['ga_account_id'] = $plugin_options['ga_accountId'];

// Update entire array
update_option( 'plugin_settings_general', $new_options );
// Delte old array
delete_option( 'plugin_options' );
```

Any end-user who might be using using your plugin's options for something in their theme, will get errors.  But if you are going to rename things, `plugin_settings_general` should be name-spaced with your plugin's actual name.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. I will test it soon. I did not want the plugin name here. I did update my question to make it clearer I hope.

Comment: I would comment out the `delete_option` while you are testing... otherwise you could delete the data before you are sure it works!

Comment: Great! I wasn't sure if you had other keys in the array. If so, just repeat the process.  If not, why have it in an array at all?

Comment: Yes, I did but wanted to keep the question simple.